# document status changes in time in firebase javascript app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a game where users are fighting each other on own devices in firestore document which is an instance of a game. The problem is that I want to create an unbreakable solution to change game status in time. So the source of truth should be firestore.

There are few statuses indicated by the game creator (created, counting), but after a few seconds of counting, I need to set a few statuses without user action. So next statuses are inProgress, scoreSummary.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.gameStateChanger = functions.firestore
    .document('rooms/{roomId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

      const roomId = context.params.roomId
      const roomRef = admin.firestore().collection('rooms').doc(roomId)

      const newValue = change.after.data()
      console.log(newValue)

      const oldValue = change.before.data()

      if(newValue.game.status==='counting') {
          setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('timeout 5s')
              roomRef.update({state: 'inProgress'})
              setTimeout(() => {
                  roomRef.update({state: 'scoreSummary'})
              }, 60000)
          }, 5000)
      }
    })
```

I tried to write a firebase function, but setTimeout in cloud function is not the best solution due to time execution limitations. I also see in the aprils update there is a firebase schedule but I want to change statuses a few seconds after the specific user clicks not every few seconds, and the schedule is also expensive.

Maybe someone has some experience with similar solutions and would tell which way should go?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to show that you are looking for delays of about 65 seconds. If that is the case, you can increase the timeout for your function to something slightly longer than 65 seconds: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Another option would be to let your client code poll every few seconds by calling a server-side function. The server-side function would check the database to see if the right amount of time has passed. If it has, the function could update the 'state' field in the database, or simply return the new state to the client.